# opencv with anaconda python2

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, opencv, python

I know there is lot of questions about it but I still can't find a useful answer.

I have anaconda installed with python 2 and i have builded my own version of opencv with cmake and visual studio, how can i connect my anaconda python2 to opencv?

When I just copy `cv2.pyd` from `opencv` into python, I can `import cv2` but `cv2.face` is missing; what can I do? I need that `cv2.face`, i am working on face recognition project.

error:

```
File "C:/Users/Gio/Desktop/Face Proj/main.py", line 54, in <module>
face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create();

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'
```

Comment: is there a `setup.py` file?

Comment: no there is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just dowloaded contrib version with pip install opencv-contrib-python and now i have extra modules

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile opencv along with contrib modules, which has the face submodule. The cmake option to do this is `-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<path to opencv_contrib>/modules`. You can download opencv contrib [here](http://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)